# Unable to display products in home page in Magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, products-view

After successful installation of `Magento 1.8.1` in a system. Everything works fine, but unable to display products on the home page. As posted on Magento website, I modified the home page design using admin interface `CMS >> Pages >> Home Page >> Design`.
As shown in the  [Magento Wiki page](https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page) below lines were added in the second line of home page design -

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

Still, the products are not displayed on home page.
What should be done to display the products on home page.
I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 server, with MySQL 5.5 database and Magento version 1.8.1 downloaded using SVN

Comment: have you checked if the file catalog/product/new.phtml exists ?

Comment: Yes it exists in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/new.phtml`

Comment: It should work than, Have you done index management ? It is necessary to do index management to make any changes in product displayed on front end.

Comment: Yes I have tried that also, but what I see is it is not calling new.phtml in the main page

Answer (score 1):

set the value for `Set Product as New from Date` for the products that need to set as new, then it will display in the new product list.

(ie) if you wants to set the product as new then the `date from and to` should be enter for that product , based on that date the product will display in the new product list

Comment: I have set the valid dates, I see that the new.html is not called on home page. What should I do for this

Comment: just call it inside the content, ie. in the `CMS >> Pages >> Home Page >> Content`

Comment: I called it, but still not able to see it on the home page.

Comment: just clear your caches and recheck

Answer (score 0):

Check if the template file **catalog/product/new.phtml** really called on your home page.

In your xml file add this and remove the block from CMS > Home Page section

```
<cms_index_index>
  <reference name="content">

  <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new"  as="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"/>

  </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```